# Using 'apply' in Pandas (externally defined function)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe, `table`, that looks like this:

```
year name     prop     sex  soundex
1880 John     0.081541 boy  J500
1880 William  0.080511 boy  W450
....
2008 Elianna  0.000127 girl E450
```

I'm trying to group `table` by `'year'`, and access select indices from the column `'name'` for each group.

My code is as follows (pretend that `special_indices` is already defined):

```
def get_indices_func(x):
    name = [x['name'].iloc[y] for y in special_indices]
    return pd.Series(name)


table.groupby(by='year').apply(get_indices_func)
```

I got the following error:

```
/Users/***/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/index.pyc in get_value(self, series, key)
    722         """
    723         try:
--> 724             return self._engine.get_value(series, key)
    725         except KeyError, e1:
    726             if len(self) > 0 and self.inferred_type == 'integer':

KeyError: 1000
```

What am I doing wrong?  I think I'm not really understanding how apply (and its cousins, aggregate and agg) works. If someone could explain, I'd be ever so grateful!

Comment: Looks like 1000 is in your special index, but not in one of the groups of data. This will try to find index position 1000 in EVERY group, whereas it looks like it does not exist in every group. Hard to sat without knowing what the special index list is though

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean.  If I were to write: name=x['name'].iloc[0], hence retrieving the first item, then everything is fine.  How would I go about specifying a different index for each group, then?

Comment: No that would not work. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to find the most popular name for each year. Is there a clever way to go about doing this?

Comment: Popular based on a count of the number of instances of 'name' in each year?

Comment: Popular based on the value of 'prop'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative solution:

```
df.groupby('year').apply(lambda x: x.sort('prop', ascending=False).iloc[0]['name'])
```

What is happening here?

First, as with Woody, we group by the correct column. `apply()` will deliver group-level data to that function. Instead, for understanding purposes, I could had written

```
define takeAGroupAndGiveBackMax(group):
    # year level data: first sort it by prop, descending
    group.sort('prop', ascending=False, inplace=True)
    # now return value 'name' of the first entry
    return group.iloc[0]['name']

# the following will give you a data set, indexed on whatever you grouped it by (here: year), and have a columns all the properties you return.    
df.groupby('year').apply(takeAGroupAndGiveBackMax)
```

In order to understand these, you should play around with the function. Try returning multiple columns, multiple rows, and you will see what `apply()` returns to you. It is really a powerful tool that pandas gives you here.

Comment: After thinking about it, I decided this is the most elegant answer. I didn't realize that putting .iloc after df.groupby... will index the desired element from each group. Brilliant!

Answer (score 2):

> I'm trying to find the most popular name for each year. Is there a
>   clever way to go about doing this?

There is a way to do this without sorting: Given a DataFrame like this:

```
In [5]: df
Out[5]: 
   year     name      prop   sex soundex
0  1880     John  0.081541   boy    J500
1  1880  William  0.080511   boy    W450
2  2008  Elianna  0.000127  girl    E450

[3 rows x 5 columns]
```

You could group by year, isolate the prop column, apply `argmax`, and use `loc` to select desired rows:

```
In [15]: df.loc[df.groupby('year')['prop'].apply(lambda x: x.argmax())]
Out[15]: 
   year     name      prop   sex soundex
0  1880     John  0.081541   boy    J500
2  2008  Elianna  0.000127  girl    E450

[2 rows x 5 columns]

In [19]: df['name'].loc[df.groupby('year')['prop'].apply(lambda x: x.argmax())]
Out[19]: 
0       John
2    Elianna
Name: name, dtype: object
```

Note that the use of `argmax` and `loc` rely on `df` having a unique index. If the DataFrame does not have a unique index you'd need make the index unique first:

```
df.reset_index()
```

---

Note that `argmax` is an `O(n)` operation, while sorting is `O(n log n)`. Even for small DataFrames, the speed advantage is noticeable:

```
In [125]: %timeit df[['year', 'name']].loc[df.groupby('year')['prop'].apply(lambda x: x.argmax())]
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.07 ms per loop

In [126]: %timeit df.groupby('year').apply(lambda x: x.sort('prop', ascending=False).iloc[0]['name'])
100 loops, best of 3: 2.14 ms per loop
```

The benchmark was run on this DataFrame:

```
In [131]: df
Out[131]: 
   year     name      prop   sex soundex
0  2008        A  0.000027  girl    E450
1  1880     John  0.081541   boy    J500
2  2008        B  0.000027  girl    E450
3  2008  Elianna  0.000127  girl    E450
4  1880  William  0.080511   boy    W450
5  2008        C  0.000027  girl    E450
6  1880        D  0.080511   boy    W450

[7 rows x 5 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  However, I might be mistaken, but I'm not sure this solution works.  df.groupby('year')['prop'].apply(lambda x: x.argmax()) returns the index for the top name for each year (incidentally, it is a list of 0's).  However, when you feed this list of indices back into df['name'], you just end up with the 0th index for the whole list, rather than the 0th index for 1880, 1881 etc.

Comment: Yes, you are right -- there was a mistake. `argmax` returns the *label* of the row, not the integer index. So I should have used `df.loc` **not** `df.iloc`.

Comment: Note that in 0.14.0 (releasing shortyly), you can bypass most of this with ``nlargest()/nsmallest()``, rather than explicity sorting (or using argmax), see here (its down a little bit): http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/basics.html#sorting-by-index-and-value

Comment: @Jeff: Very cool! Are you thinking of `df.groupby('year')['prop'].apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(1))` or something more direct? (If so, how do you get the `name` associated with the highest `prop` for each year?)

Comment: yes (I think their is an issue to add ``nlargest()`` to the groupby whitelist, so ``df.groupby('year')['prop'].nlargest(1)``

Answer (score 1):

try something like this: Define an aggregation function that sorts each group of data by prop (to do this you have to make a copy). The function returns the first row of that copied and sorted data (i.e. with the highest value of prop). pass this function to `.agg` and group the data by year.

```
def get_most_popular(x):
    y = x.copy()
    y.sort('prop')
    return y.iloc[0]

df.groupby('year').agg(get_most_popular)
```

Comment: You could simplify it to the following:  `df.groupby('year').agg(lambda x: x.loc[x['prop'].idxmax(),:])`

Comment: I agree that `.copy()` is an unneeded cause of inefficiency - isn't it?

Comment: could well be, but its the only way to sort the grouped data in this case

Comment: Cool, I got an error telling me I needed a copy. No biggie